# BitBucket/Git - Creating a new file + merging to master

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge

I'm using [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org) (similar to [GitHub](https://github.com)), and I'm trying to create a new file and add some code to my repository. What I tried is navigating to where I want the new file, clicking the [three dots in the top right corner](https://gyazo.com/91e8a45d6e39f2d5aaa71f4704b675cf), then clicking `Add File`. I then gave it a name, `view.js`, pasted my code, then committed, pulled, and merged to master. However, when I go back and check on my file, it hasn't been created. The merge was successful, however. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Note: This is from the web interface.

Comment: Are you actually trying to add files from the web interface?  I would recommend just doing your work locally, if possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah, it is from the web interface. How would I do this locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to add files from the Bitbucket web interface, but typically in development you would add files locally using the Git bash, or maybe a plugin which really sits on top of the bash.  Adding a file to a branch is simple:

```
git checkout some_branch
# create a new file, edit it, etc.
git add path/to/new/file.ext
git commit -m 'Added a new file'
git push origin some_branch
```

Comment: When running `git commit -m 'Added a new file'`, I get `On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   package-lock.json
        modified:   package.json

no changes added to commit`

Comment: @apxx Are you sure that `git commit` generated that error message?  I would expect to see that from `git push`.  If so, you just need to do a `git pull` to bring in the latest changes from the remote repository.

Comment: It says that everything is up to date

Comment: I also tried redoing the process but now I get `fatal: pathspec 'my/path/to/newfile.js' did not match any files`

Comment: Let me ask you: Did you _clone_ your repo to get the local copy?

Comment: Nope, I was originally working on my local machine but then decided to use BitBucket, and so I created a new repo and pushed my files over

Comment: Edit your question and show the steps you took to initialize your repo.  I think you took a wrong turn somewhere.